# Select rows based on two columns and sort it out according to a third one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm developing an in-game shop for the game Minecraft, in which an item is defined as a pair of a Material string and a Data integer. Each advertised item is inserted in a table of a MySQL database with a price integer associated to it and the same item can be advertised multiple times with the same price or not, like in the example below, where the items (ink_sack, 3) and (apple, 0) appear twice:

```
+----------+------+-------+
| material | data | price |
+----------+------+-------+
| ink_sack |    0 |     1 |
| ink_sack |    3 |     2 |
| ink_sack |    3 |     6 | 
|    apple |    0 |     2 |
|    apple |    0 |     5 |
|iron_sword|    0 |    10 |
```

What I want is to retrieve the entry for each possible item (pair of Material and Data) with the lowest price, like in the following example:

```
+----------+------+-------+
| material | data | price |
+----------+------+-------+
| ink_sack |    0 |     1 |
| ink_sack |    3 |     2 |
|    apple |    0 |     2 |
|iron_sword|    0 |    10 |
```

However, I don't have any idea of how to do that considering these pairs of values instead of a single column when using the `LEAST` keyword or even if thats the right option in this case. How should I do that with a single query and no post-processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the records by the columns you want to be unique. aggregate functions like `min()` apply to each group

```
select material, data, min(price) as min_price
from your_table
group by material, data
```

Comment: There is a mistake !
This query don't give the result in sorted order with 'price' values.
You must use ORDER BY clause with column name of price  at the end of the query .

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !
Here I am using 'GROUP BY' clause which makes the group according to the data & material in the table ,then apply the aggregate function of minimum 'min' on the price column of group data & sort it by price using 'ORDER BY' clause.
Also I am attaching the screenshot of the result of query.

```
SELECT 
      material  ,
      data      ,
      min(price) AS price
FROM 
      [Table Name]
GROUP BY
      data      , 
      material
ORDER BY 
      price
```

[image: Output of Query]